Issues Testing Subscriptions in TestFlight: Main Account Instead of Sandbox
I'm developing an iOS app with a subscription model and facing issues testing subscriptions via TestFlight.
Initially, during testing, the subscription renewal in TestFlight worked as expected, renewing around every 20 minutes. However, recently, it seems the renewal period has changed to one day (or possibly six days, but I'm not sure yet).
What I've Tried:

TestFlight Subscription Tests

When subscribing through the app downloaded from TestFlight, the subscription is made using my main Apple ID instead of the sandbox account.


Sandbox Account Setup

I created a sandbox account in App Store Connect Sandbox and then connected it in App Store > SANDBOX ACCOUNT .
Cleared the purchase history of the sandbox account.
Despite this, subscriptions seem to continue with my main account, not the sandbox account.


Subscription Management

Checked both the main account and the sandbox account for active subscriptions, but neither shows any active subscriptions.
I suspect my main Apple ID is subscribed, but I can't verify it through the usual account management pages.



Questions:

How can I ensure TestFlight uses the sandbox account for subscriptions instead of my main account?
Is it possible to reset or completely remove active TestFlight subscriptions linked to my main account?
Does anyone have insights into why the renewal period in TestFlight testing has changed (from 20 minutes to 1-6 days)?


Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

If you prefer I can write in an english nobody will understand, it will be better if everyone can read me.

TestFlight is intended to allow testing of an App Store release candidate and purchases made with a TestFlight build are made using the production sandbox, which is different to the sandbox you use in development. No payment is collected with production sandbox purchases.
The use of then production sandbox means that:

The purchase is made with "real" Apple IDs, not sandbox IDs
Purchases cannot be removed from the purchase history.
You cannot see the purchase history in the normal place (because that shows production purchases, not production sandbox purchases)
You cannot manage subscriptions (again because the subscription management cannot see production sandbox subscriptions)

Apple has recently (December 2024) changed TestFlight subscriptions to renew once per 24 hours, regardless of the subscription duration. After 6 renewals, the subscription is cancelled and no longer renews.

Thanks for the explanation so how do you test the subscription process, you can test it once per week?

You should be testing the subscription process with your development builds. TestFlight is intended for beta testing your entire app, potentially with a broad range of users.

Is there any way to export and make install a development build because the non dev guys from the team will not be able to use git nor run xcode

As long as you have their device UDIDs registered in your developer portal and associated with the dev provisioning profile you can give them an ad-hoc build to run on their device. There are various CI tools that can make this easier (but you still need their UDIDs)
